# read from pointer argument of a c++ function in python with pybind11

Tags: c++, c++11, pybind11

I have a c++ function like:

```
int add(int *i, int j) {
    *i += 3;
    return *i + j;
}
```

I have created python binding for it using pybind11 as

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = R"pbdoc(add)pbdoc";
    m.def("add", &add, R"pbdoc(Add two numbers)pbdoc");
}
```

I call it in python as:

```
>>import example
>>a=1
>>example.add(a,2)
>>6 --> This is correct
>>a
>>1 --> This is not what expect
```

It returns 6, which is correct
However, when I print "a", it still prints 1 instead of 4.
How can i modify the pybind11 definition, so that changes done in argument value inside C++ as visible in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You cannot](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#limitations-involving-reference-arguments). Your variable `a` is a reference to a *constant* integer.

In this instance you must *rebind* the reference to the result: `a = example.add(a, 2)`. Alternatively you can wrap the integer in a type you can mutate.

Comment: how to wrap the integer immutable in  a type that is mutable in python? can you give an example? thanks!